# Laravel running on Laradock - Getting Nginx Error 504 Gateway Time Out

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, laradock

First time with docker and serving a project to production. I've uploaded a laravel project to a vps, running with **laradock**. These are the containers that are running on my machine right now:

```
docker-compose ps
```

[image: docker-compose ps result]

The command that I executed was: `docker-compose up -d nginx mysql`, after reading the laradock [docs](https://laradock.io/)

All is working correctly and the server runs smooth, but I have one problem that is driving me crazy. When I try to make a certain action on my website that needs a bit more of time, the browser gets stuck reloading and I get this error:

[image]

I've tried changing config files both on **laradock/nginx/nginx.conf**, **laradock/php-fpm/php7.3.ini** and **laradock/php-fpm/laravel.ini** and building the docker again, but I don't know if I am changing the correct values in the correct laradock files or if I haven't rebuild the docker images/containers correctly, as I said it's my first time doing this and I don't know what to do.

Can someone please tell me what can I do to solve this? The only post that I've found similar to mine was this [one](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/304)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Check out the first answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672340/504-gateway-time-out-media-temple might help you figure out what you need to change

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know where nginx.conf is, but exactly which php.ini should I change with laradock? Inside php-fpm there are a lot of folders :( And after I change the files, which command should I execute to make docker get this new config?